# change image src based on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

i'm using Shopify platform and i try to add flags images to my currency converter

The following is my currency converter code

```html
<select id="currencies" class="currencies" name="currencies" data-default-shop-currency="{{ shop.currency }}">
  {% capture codes %},USD,EUR,GBP,CAD,ARS,AUD,ILS,BBD,BDT,BSD,BHD,BRL,BOB,BND,BGN,MMK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,HRK,CZK,DKK,DOP,XCD,EGP,XPF,FJD,GHS,GTQ,GYD,GEL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,NIS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,LVL,LTL,MXN,MYR,MUR,MDL,MAD,MNT,MZN,ANG,NZD,NGN,NOK,OMR,PKR,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RON,RUB,SAR,RSD,SCR,SGD,SYP,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SEK,CHF,TWD,THB,TZS,TTD,TRY,UAH,AED,UYU,VEB,VND,ZMK,{% endcapture %}
  {% assign supported_codes = settings.supported_currencies | split: ' ' %}
  <option value="{{ shop.currency }}" selected="selected">{{ shop.currency }}</option>
  {% for code in supported_codes %}
    {% if code != shop.currency and codes contains code %}
    <option value="{{ code }}">{{ code }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and this is the Java i made:

```js
var flagsArray = [
  "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/usa.png?18222330839739856022", // USD,
  "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/GBP.png?10208443253961150348", // GBP,
  "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/ILS.png?16971579683524372576"  // ILS ...
];

$('#currencies').change(function(){
  $('#flags')[0].src = flagsArray[this.value];
});
```

it supposed to change the picture when the value change.

(the value MOST to be USD, GBP ect... Can't be number because this is how the currency changer bulid)

and this is the img the should change when i change the currency:

```html
<img id="flags" src='//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/usa.png?18222330839739856022'>
```

i don't know what i do wrong, if anybody can tell me it would be great :)
thanks :)

Comment: why is this tagged as `java` ? what is the language used in the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the value of the array instead of the index of the array. You can use `.indexOf()` or `.findIndex()` to get the index of the array that matches the current value of `select` element, where you appear to set the `value` attribute of the `<option>` elements

```
<option value="{{ code }}">{{ code }}</option>
```

to the string that is set at `flagsArray` elements at JavaScript rather than an index corresponding to the index of the `flagsArray` which should be referenced

```
flagsArray[flags.indexOf(this.value)];
```

or

```
flagsArray[flags.findIndex(function(text){return text === this.value})];
```

Alternatively, you can set the `value` of the `<option>` element corresponding to the index of the array which should be matched

```
<option value="{{ index //? }}">{{ code }}</option>
```

for ability to use current code